# Unable to exclude lines containing ^M from grep

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep, tr

I have the following file from which I want to extract only `Removed '2022-01-30_01-00-05'`, at the end.

```
Removing '2022-01-30_01-00-05'...
  0.46% complete (00:03:45 remaining)^M  5.49% complete (00:00:17 remaining)^M 24.90% complete (00:00:06 remaining)^M 60.56% complete (00:00:01 remaining)^M 82.12% complete (00:00:00 remaining)^M 82.39% complete (00:00:01 remaining)^M 84.24% complete (00:00:01 remaining)^M 86.48% complete (00:00:01 remaining)^M 88.58% complete (00:00:01 remaining)^M 89.66% complete (00:00:01 remaining)^M101.08% complete (00:00:00 remaining)^M104.62% complete (00:00:00 remaining)^M                                                                                ^MRemoved '2022-01-30_01-00-05'
```

I've tried `dos2unix` but it didn't work.

I've tried these variations, below, but when I `less output` they either don't remove the `^M` characters, or the whole line is captured:

```
tr -d $'\r' < /file | grep "Removed" > output
tr -d '^M' < /file | grep "Removed" > output
tr -d ^M < /file | grep "Removed" > output
sed 's/\r//g' < /file | grep "Removed" > output
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `grep` command will print the entire matching line and since lines in *nix are defined by `\n` and not `\r`, what you describe is normal behavior. In other words, your first and last commands (the `tr -d '\r'` and the `sed 's/\r//g'`) are both working as intended, it's just that grep is doing what it's supposed to do and printing the entire line.

To only print *part* of a line, you need GNU `grep` and its `-o` option. For example:

```
$ grep -oP "Removed\s*'[^']+'" file
Removed '2022-01-30_01-00-05'
```

Alternatively, change the `\r` (the `^M`) to newline characters instead of deleting them:

```
$ tr '\r' '\n' < file | grep Removed
Removed '2022-01-30_01-00-05'
```

Or

```
$ sed 's/\r/\n/g' file | grep Removed
Removed '2022-01-30_01-00-05'
```

Comment: Also `tr '\r' '\n' <file | tail -n 1`, or `tail -n 1 file | sed 's/.*\r//'`.

Answer (score 5):

`dos2unix` strips control-Ms (`\r`) from immediately before the end of lines (`\n`) - that's not what you have, you have control-Ms **instead of** end of lines. Hence `dos2unix` not helping you.

With GNU awk for multi-chars RS and using any sequence of `\r`s and/or `\n`s as the record separators:

```
$ awk -v RS='[\r\n]+' '/^Removed/' file
Removed '2022-01-30_01-00-05'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /Removed/){print $i,$(i+1)}}}' filename| awk '{gsub(/\^M/,"",$0);print }'
```

output

```
Removed '2022-01-30_01-00-05'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input file has Mac line breaks. You can convert them to Unix line breaks with

```
dos2unix -c mac file
```

or

```
mac2unix file
```

To find out which type of line breaks your file has you can use this command:

```
dos2unix -ih file
```